# Running DSODB on Netezza

Tags: netezza, datastage, information-server

I'm looking for guidance or instructions to allow Information Server's DSODB database to be located on a Netezza Appliance.

has anyone been able to do this?
I realize the guidance say ORACLE, MSSQL, and DB2, but if anyone knows how to put it on Netezza, that would be of great interest.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is more than just guidance to use Db2, Oracle or SQL Server. Likely only those DBMS are supported for the operations database. Netezza is lacking things like indexes and enforced primary and foreign keys, so is likely not suitable for the DSODB